# chosing keyboard layout using vb.net code

Tags: vb.net

I have installed Phoenetic Key board for Urdu language, that I can select from Control Panel > Languages > Keyboard
Can I add languages and select keyboard using my vb.net code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage property lets you switch keyboard layouts.  Not so sure it can deal with multiple layouts for a single language but I don't really know what "Phoenetic Key board" really means.  The underlying Windows api functions are LoadKeyboardLayout() and ActivateKeyboardLayout(), you could pinvoke them.  GetKeyboardLayoutList() to get a list of installed layouts, you probably need that, GetKeyboardLayoutName() to get a description of a layout.  Also covered by the InputLanguage class.

You normally leave it up to the user to select keyboard layouts, forcing your preference is pretty hostile to usability.  Easy to do with the language bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your application Input language this way:

```vb
InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = InputLanguage.FromCulture(New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ZH-CN"))
```

but if you don't have the required `InputLanguage` Installed you can install your cultures input language from code temporary by using windows api:

```vb
<DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function UnloadKeyboardLayout(hkl As IntPtr) As Boolean
End Function
<DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function LoadKeyboardLayout(pwszKLID As String, Flags As UInteger) As IntPtr
End Function

Public Class KeyboardHolder
    Implements IDisposable
    Private ReadOnly pointer As IntPtr
    Public Sub New(klid As Integer)
        pointer = LoadKeyboardLayout(klid.ToString("X8"), 1)
    End Sub
    Public Sub New(culture As CultureInfo)
        Me.New(culture.KeyboardLayoutId)
    End Sub
    Public Sub Dispose()
        UnloadKeyboardLayout(pointer)
        GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
    End Sub
    Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
        Try
            UnloadKeyboardLayout(pointer)
        Finally
            MyBase.Finalize()
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

and use it this way:

```vb
' install keyboard layout temporary
Dim keyboard As New KeyboardHolder(New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ZH-CN"))

' after finishing what you want remove temporary added keyboard layout:
keyboard.Dispose()
```